# HTML <li> items not rendered correctly in Firefox, Edge, and IE11

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, markdown

[This Sandbox post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/326046/2) looks quite normal when viewed on e.g. Safari or Chrome:

[image: list shown properly in Safari or Chrome]

but when viewed in Firefox (on macOS Mojave) as well as Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer 11, the bullets generated by `<li>` items (instead of using Markdown `-` or `*`) are aligned *over* the blockquote or even outside the post:

[image: list shown incorrectly in Firefox]

This is the markdown used for the above test:

```
> <li> This is a test to show a formatting bug.

<li> This is a test to show a formatting bug.

> - This is a test to show a formatting bug.

- This is a test to show a formatting bug.
```

Comment: Confirm the same results in Chromium on Linux.

Comment: When using invalid HTML, it's expected that browsers won't show it properly. Some might try and fix the invalid HTML with "best guess", but it's not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting an `<li>` element directly inside something that is not an ordered or unordered list is not valid HTML and inherently does not have a defined behavior. If the post correctly uses a parent list, it renders perfectly fine:

> - This is a test to show a formatting bug.

- This is a test to show a formatting bug.

> - This is a test to show a formatting bug.

- This is a test to show a formatting bug.

You'll notice that even in Chrome and Safari, your first screenshot still renders incorrectly (the bullets for the first two are shifted further to the left) due to the lack of a parent list element. It *must* exist.